# Resizing objects when entering full screen mode in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

Consider the following Flex code:

```
private function fullScreenHandler(evt:FullScreenEvent):void {
  if (evt.fullScreen) {
    viewstack.selectedIndex = 2;
    objectInViewStack2.width = [code to detect width when in full screen mode];
    objectInViewStack2.height = [code to detect height when in full screen mode];
  } else {
     viewstack.selectedIndex = 1;
  }
}
```

I have a viewstack with two containing canvases. Canvas 1 is used when in normal mode and canvas 2 which is used when in full screen mode.

To properly resize the `objectInViewStack2` I need to know how large the screen is when in full screen mode.

What is the proper way to solve the given problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Capabilities](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2) class.

Specifically I would recommend looking at [screenResolutionY](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#screenResolutionY) and [screenResolutionX](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#screenResolutionX).

However, you may also consider sizing your child elements in updateDisplayList(), which will always give you the the height and width of your container, which I suspect is more important for sizing purposes than the screen resolution.